# Most efficient way for popping max node from a queue implemented using a linked list? C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, max

If you have a fifo queue implemented using a linked list, what would be the most efficient way to pop a node with the highest value?

Mergesort would be O(n log n).
Scanning through the list would be O(n).

Can anyone suggest more efficient ways of doing this?

The queue must retain the fifo ordering that operates in the usual manner with enqueue and dequeue, but has an extra method, such as popMax, which pops and returns the node with the highest value.

No code is needed, just some ideas! Thanks!

Comment: _"Node code is needed"_ Nope, you show yours first. We're not a code writing service!

Comment: You may have two *lists*, one for fifo, one for max.

Comment: Define what you mean by most efficient.  Time or space?  The ultimate answer depends on how you will use it.

Comment: For that basic combination of requirements (which has come up surprisingly often in my career) I always code my own priority queue (heap) of node pointers and have a node member to hold the index of the heap position.  Then either structure can be accessed to select items to be removed from both.

Comment: @Jarod42, two lists would be pointless, you are adding complexity and storage, not to save any time, but just to move the time from `popMax` into `enqueue`

Comment: Sorry that meant to say no code is needed....

Answer (score 0):

Is popMax frequent enough that changing it from O(N) to O(logN) justifies extra storage (per node: two pointers plus an index) and extra complexity **AND** changing enqueue and dequeue from O(1) to O(logN) ??

In the many times I have solved this problem (for different reasons and different employers) the answer to the above has pretty consistently been "Yes".  But it might be "no" for you.  So first make that decision.

Any improvement on the O(N) needs to be able to remove from the middle of the primary sequence.  If the primary sequence would have been a forward only linked list, now it needs links in both directions:  One extra pointer.

A heap of pointers, costs another extra pointer (per node, but not in the node).  But then dequeue needs to be able to remove from the middle of the heap, which takes an index within the node as a back pointer to its position in the heap.

If it is worth all that, you can easily find (online free) source code for a templated version of a priorityQueue/heap and it should be obvious how to make the heap, objects be `node*` and the `less` function given to the heap compare the values inside the nodes pointed to.

Next you change that heap source code (the reason you don't simply use std::priority_queue) such that each time it positions an "object" (meaning a `node*`) in the queue, it does some kind of callback to notify the object of its new index.

You also need to expose some internals of the heap code.  There is a point in any decent version of heap code in which the code deals with a hole (missing element) at index x within the heap, by checking whether the last element of the heap could be correctly moved there (and if so doing that) or if not moving the correct child of the hole into the hole and repeating for the new hole where that child was.  Typically that code is not exposed to external callers with x as an input.  But it easily can be exposed.  Your `dequeue` function needs that in order to remove from the heap the same element being removed from the list.

For less extra storage, but likely more execution time (though still O(logN) for each function).  You could have a heap of nodes instead of a heap of `node*`.  That is the reason in coding this kind of heap, you should code the notify callback generically (similar to `less`).  Then your doubly linked list has indexes instead of pointers (so growth is robust) and the notify function updates the predecessor's forward index and successor's back index.  To avoid lots of special casing, you need to have a full circle (maybe including a dummy node) of double links, rather than just end to end.

I haven't worked through the details yet myself (since I've never redone any of this in the post C++11 world) but I think a more elegant alternative to the notify function discussed above would be to wrap the object (that will be in the heap) in a wrapper that allows it to be moved but doesn't allow it to be copied.  The action to be done by notify would instead be done during the move.  That makes std::priority_queue even closer to what you need, but so far as I understand, it still doesn't expose that key internal point in the code for filling a hole at an arbitrary location.

Comment: Sorry, should of added more detail, yes the node already has two pointed (prev and next), it's a doubly. It also has two ints, ID and priority (ordered by priority)

Comment: So the most elegant solution is to store the nodes themselves in the heap (sorted by priority) and use C++11 move semantics to trigger repair of the pointers whenever a node moves within the heap.

Comment: sorry again! Trying to avoid any STL

Comment: That's good, because the STL heap or priority queue fails to expose a key internal method you need.  So you would need to rewrite the important parts of std::priority_queue from scratch anyway.  But that turns out to be a rather small amount of easy code, if you know what that meaning of "heap" is (not the malloc meaning).